# I need help understanding the alignment of options in IPv6 Packets

Tags: python, ip, ipv6, packet-sniffers, sniffing

I am trying to write a simple packet sniffer in Python. I am looking at [RFC 2560 Section 4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2460#section-4.2) about the options and it starts talking about padding the options and that the options section must start at a certain offset. I must have read it a dozen times, but it seems almost to contradict itself. It says that specific option types have different alignment requirements that determine where the *Option Type* section starts, but how are we supposed to tell where the *Option Type* section is supposed to be if we haven't seen what type of option it is yet? And doesn't the sub-header it is a part of have its own padding for the options section? These are the things that are confusing me.

Where does the option start, end, and where is the padding actually supposed to be?

Comment: You don't need to worry about this when parsing the options, only when sending a packet with options. The sender adds padding options before the options that require special alignment, and when you're parsing you just skip over the padding options.